# No desktop showing Dell Latitude D531 

Tags: installation, graphics, desktop-background

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a Dell D531 Laptop instead of Windows 7. The install finished and I rebooted the laptop. To install Ubuntu 11.10, I used a cd. When logged in, the screen shows the background only. I'm now afraid I've made my laptop into a paperweight.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. To work around it, I picked the non-3D graphics option on the login screen.

On a side note, my wireless works fine after loading the STA driver.

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl+alt+f1 and see if you can log in in text mode. if you can, then your problem is with your graphic card, I belive this NB uses ATI graphic card. I do not know much about this but if you give more details someone can give you a good answer.